# Spotify Python API call timeout issues

Tags: python, api, spotify

I am getting below error on Spotify API call. is there work around to resolve these timeout issues.
[Python Spotify Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuELc.png)

TimeoutError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address, socket_options)
73                 sock.bind(source_address)
---> 74             sock.connect(sa)
75             return sock

TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
KeyboardInterrupt                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-eb4cef5ffdbb> in <module>
      5     #print(artist)
      6     #time.sleep(2)
----> 7     result = spotify.search(artist,search_type='artist')['artists']['items']
      8     #print(result)
      9     try:

<ipython-input-7-6a2d183a2f3a> in search(self, query, search_type)
     80         data = urlencode({"q": query, "type": search_type.lower()})
     81         lookup_url = f"{endpoint}?{data}"
---> 82         r = requests.get(lookup_url, headers=headers)#.json()
     83         if r.status_code not in range(200, 299):
     84             return {}

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py in get(url, params, **kwargs)
     74 
     75     kwargs.setdefault('allow_redirects', True)
---> 76     return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
     77 
     78 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py in request(method, url, **kwargs)
     59     # cases, and look like a memory leak in others.
     60     with sessions.Session() as session:
---> 61         return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
     62 
     63 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    528         }
    529         send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 530         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    531 
    532         return resp

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in send(self, request, **kwargs)
    641 
    642         # Send the request
--> 643         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    644 
    645         # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    437         try:
    438             if not chunked:
--> 439                 resp = conn.urlopen(
    440                     method=request.method,
    441                     url=url,

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    668 
    669             # Make the request on the httplib connection object.
--> 670             httplib_response = self._make_request(
    671                 conn,
    672                 method,

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    379         # Trigger any extra validation we need to do.
    380         try:
--> 381             self._validate_conn(conn)
    382         except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError) as e:
    383             # Py2 raises this as a BaseSSLError, Py3 raises it as socket timeout.

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in _validate_conn(self, conn)
    974         # Force connect early to allow us to validate the connection.
    975         if not getattr(conn, "sock", None):  # AppEngine might not have  `.sock`
--> 976             conn.connect()
    977 
    978         if not conn.is_verified:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py in connect(self)
    306     def connect(self):
    307         # Add certificate verification
--> 308         conn = self._new_conn()
    309         hostname = self.host
    310 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py in _new_conn(self)
    157 
    158         try:
--> 159             conn = connection.create_connection(
    160                 (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
    161             )

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address, socket_options)
     72             if source_address:
     73                 sock.bind(source_address)
---> 74             sock.connect(sa)
     75             return sock
     76 

KeyboardInterrupt: 

1
###########Create Data frame with required columns to be extracte


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCaz4.p
```

ng

Answer (score 3):

I really wish spotipy would address this issue in their package, but nonetheless, here's my workaround:

1. Import the error type

If you don't catch this exact error type, you'll cause problems for yourself by leaving your catch open-ended. For example, if you have a `TypeError` in your syntax or something, it will error that out and go to your catch block, and you'll have no way of knowing that it errored in the first place.

`from requests.exceptions import ReadTimeout`

2. When you init your spotipy client, I recommend adding in a couple of params that might be helpful.

```
spotify = spotipy.Spotify(auth=spotify_token, requests_timeout=10, retries=10)
```

- requests_timeout | throws the same error you're looking for after a number of seconds. I use this just so that it doesn't hang forever, and it'll just retry the request if nothing comes back after 10 seconds.
- retries | the maximum number of retries spotipy will request if it gets an error. I think it defaults to 3, so I just like to increase this a little bit just in case.

3. Run a try/except type retry system

You can definitely expand this to make it keep retrying (using a while loop or something) if it keeps hanging, but this is the basic idea:

```
try:

  result = spotify.search(artist,search_type='artist')['artists']['items']

except ReadTimeout:

  print('Spotify timed out... trying again...')
  result = spotify.search(artist,search_type='artist')['artists']['items']
```