# What does this error means? Python/Spotipy/Spotify API

Tags: python, spotipy

I'm running a Python app which continuously update the title of my Spotify Playlist if it changes without my approval (you can check this [link](https://techcrunch.com/2021/09/08/spotify-playlist-curators-complain-about-ongoing-abuse-that-favors-bad-actors-over-innocent-parties/?guccounter=1&guce_referrer=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8&guce_referrer_sig=AQAAADqvkn47cNzWa2I3O43KtPuxHY4dHo0-NALtnygZwVbUiF9elQL8S7TmpUXplurY0pjI6q2oMFhVi-0V9y4clEx9fX7J7hL2pYN2obtfBrYJ29aOoCPa-PFjrZYF65ngKSUgeKqSGCUbtyOrHEoJx0B8AMCJM4MpzhXEMN4vHFqz) if you want to know why).

The code is really simple:

```
    import time
import schedule
import spotipy
import spotipy.util as util
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth

import base64
with open("C:\\Users\\You\\YourWorkingDirectory\\Data\\PlaylistPhoto.jpeg", "rb") as img_file:
    myimage = base64.b64encode(img_file.read())

print("Starting Playlist updater")
  
def func():
    scope = 'playlist-modify-public ugc-image-upload'

    # Spotify Username
    username = 'username'

    # Spotify Developer App Client ID and Secret ID
    SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID = 'clientid'
    SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET = 'clientsecret'

    token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username,scope,SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID,SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET,redirect_uri='http://yourdomain.com')
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)

    # Playlist Data
    id = 'https://open.spotify.com/playlist/yourplaylist'
    playlist_name = 'Playlist Name'
    playlist_description = 'Playlist Description'
    image_b64 = myimage

    sp.playlist_upload_cover_image(playlist_id=id, image_b64 = myimage)
    sp.user_playlist_change_details(username, id, name=playlist_name, description=playlist_description)

    print("Playlist updated")

func()
schedule.every(5).minutes.do(func)
  
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(30)
    continue
```

Today I got this error, after PYTHON/IDLE was running from like 24 hours. Where do you think it came from?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 785, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 550, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 770, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 451, in _make_request
    self._raise_timeout(err=e, url=url, timeout_value=read_timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 340, in _raise_timeout
    raise ReadTimeoutError(
urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.spotify.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=5)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Sapore VERO\Sapore.py", line 41, in <module>
    schedule.run_pending()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\schedule\__init__.py", line 780, in run_pending
    default_scheduler.run_pending()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\schedule\__init__.py", line 100, in run_pending
    self._run_job(job)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\schedule\__init__.py", line 172, in _run_job
    ret = job.run()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\schedule\__init__.py", line 661, in run
    ret = self.job_func()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Sapore VERO\Sapore.py", line 32, in func
    sp.playlist_upload_cover_image(playlist_id=id, image_b64 = myimage)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\spotipy\client.py", line 700, in playlist_upload_cover_image
    return self._put(
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\spotipy\client.py", line 312, in _put
    return self._internal_call("PUT", url, payload, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\spotipy\client.py", line 240, in _internal_call
    response = self._session.request(
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 529, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 645, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 532, in send
    raise ReadTimeout(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.spotify.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=5)
```

Comment: *"Where do you think it came from?"* - we shouldn't need to guess... Please provide a [mre]. You should also take the [tour] and read about [ask]

Comment: Traceback message tells that it didn't get any response in 5 seconds from spotify server. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66770782/5702135) will help?

Comment: It might also be related to [rate limiting](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/guides/rate-limits/)

Comment: @Tomerikoo thank you for your answer! The app is developed to constantly update the title every 5 minutes, so rate limiting shouldn't be an issue :/

Comment: @LeeM.U. So you think that adding something like: sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token, requests_timeout=10, retries=10) Could possibly help? :)

Comment: @Blurryface One of the advantages of programming I think is that in most cases, code rarely causes permanent damage in real life. So why don't you give it a try?